# Android ScheduledExecutorService scheduleAtFixedRate works not properly

Tags: android, multithreading, background-process

I've setted ScheduledExecutorService to print every 5 seconds:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("working");
    }
}, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Everything works perfect, but after the activity went to onPause() plus few minutes it starts to print with random intervals.

The example of the normal work:

```
10-17 11:05:04.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:09.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:14.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:19.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:24.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:29.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:34.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:39.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:44.865: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:49.855: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:54.855: I/System.out(3863): working: 
10-17 11:05:59.865: I/System.out(3863): working:
```

The example how it works after onPause() activity + few minutes:

```
10-17 11:24:21.825: I/System.out(3959): Fragment onPause
10-17 11:24:35.484: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:24:43.533: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:24:52.084: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:25:15.490: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:25:34.908: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:25:59.146: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:26:18.385: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:26:45.162: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:27:24.991: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:27:55.735: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:28:35.301: I/System.out(3959): working
10-17 11:29:12.415: I/System.out(3959): working
```

Is it a normal for this thing? Is it any alternatives to scheduleAtFixedRate? (I don't want to use Service since in normal app I'm going to schedule the task with the rate of 24 hours, and I don't want this event to fire when the app is not running, so AlarmManager is not that I want also).

Answer (score 0):

The android documentation says following about ExecutorService scheduled tasks

> Beware however that expiration of a relative delay need not coincide
>   with the current Date at which the task is enabled due to network time
>   synchronization protocols, clock drift, or other factors. The
>   Executors class provides convenient factory methods for the
>   ScheduledExecutorService implementations provided in this package.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Maybe it's a clock drift thing, or maybe some other activity threads which are in the foreground get executed at higher priority and your ES gets a chance later.

Comment: It was told to be aware of use date.getTime(), but I use hard-coded 5 seconds.

Comment: well, "5 seconds" is a relative term, maybe something wrong happens to the system clock and 5 becomes 7 or 4 :)

Comment: And if I will set it to 24 hours it fires every 72 and 120 hours. I suppose that you were right about the priority (but I'm not sure about it), and if it haven't had priority in time it should fire, it will not try to fire again in 5/7/10 seconds, it will try in 24 hours (and here we again get low priority).

Comment: for long term events, maybe you should try Alarm services, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html